# Preserve whitespace between concurent HTML elements in raw markup

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I need to render raw HTML on page using twig. Issue that I'm having is that when I have two concurrent HTML element separated by white-space, that white-space gets removed.

How can I preserve that space?

I'm rendering HTML string as so:

```
{{ set _html = entity.html }}
{{ _html|raw }}
```

For example:

```
<p>start <span class="some-class">one</span> <span class="some-class">two</span> stop</p>
```

Is rendered as:

```
<p>start <span class="some-class">one</span><span class="some-class">two</span> stop</p>
```

I'm sure that twig `raw` function is sanitizing my data and therefore my issue.

How I see it:

[image]

Comment: The `raw` filter only prevents the auto escaping behaviour, it should not mess with white spaces. I tried your code in this [twig fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/k9tp52) and could not reproduce the issue. Are you using [`spaceless`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html) or something similar?

Comment: You're right, `strong` tag does actually preserve the whitespace (yes I was using the `spaceless` which now I have removed it). The `span` does not. Please see updated example.

Comment: Well, I updated the [twig fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/k9tp52) accordingly and I can't seem to reproduce the issue there. Are you using [this kind of notation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#templates-whitespace-control) in your template?

Comment: I see the converter issue. I attached image how it renders. Perhaps it's not twig related at all.

Comment: What did you use to display the ENCODED section? Simply `{{ _html }}`? Maybe you should dump `entity.html` before it is even passed to twig to check if the value is correct at that point.

Comment: correct. just `{{ _html }}`.

Comment: Updated image with `{{ dump(_html) }}`.

Comment: Well maybe it is related to some CSS associated to `.formal_usage` then.

Comment: Checked, all class does is make text italic. Also, when removing ALL styles doesn't help.

Comment: As a side-note, I'd recommend NOT leaving the whitespace and relying on it for layout, but rather putting the elements "tight" together and handling the space via CSS.

Comment: @cale_b, that's what I will do. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried just adding &nbsp; instead of a whitespace?

Comment: @Christoph Dietrich, yes. It is also stripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870729/cale-b) recommended, I will be using following CSS hack to add a space before element that lacks my spacing:

```
.monograph {
  * + span:before {
    content: ' ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575331/twig-how-to-disable-removing-white-spaces) and also in my case, the issue was that I had a `{% spaceless %}` tag that wrapped my content. So `|raw` was working correctly but it was the spaceless tag that was stripping the spaces.