# Twig how to disable removing white spaces

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a symfony  project with twig as a template engine. I use **raw** filter to display HTML content after syntax highlight (by using highlight.php, unfortunately I'm not able to use js version as I make an **AMP** page). Twig removed all white spaces which makes the code useless. The code is in pre tag also spaces are missing in generated HTML code.

Is there anyway to disable removing whitespaces in twig?

I know it would be fixed if I switch to php templates.

Comment: if by "white-spaces" you mean spaces non-breaking spaces, then it won't happen just in twig... HTML, PHP, and more ignore white spaces... More accurately, they turn a succession of white-spaces into a single space. Use `&nbsp;` instead, it won't be trimmed

Comment: it is in pre tag, I forgot to add that info. Also I am checking the source code where spaces are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue. In some parent template there was {% spaceless %} which was removing white spaces!

Answer (score 5):

To add space between two words use below code:

```
{{ price|replace({" ": "&nbsp;"})|raw|nl2br }}
```

This will work.